# How to pass more than 2 parameters in javascript dynamic click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following the code for dynamic click event.

```
var myTeamName = {
    val1 : 'Team1',
    val2 : 'Team2',
    val3 : 'Team3',
    val4 : 'Team4',
    val5 : 'Team5',
    val6 : 'Team6',
    val7 : 'Team7',
    val8 : 'Team8',
    val9 : 'Team9',
    val10 : 'Team10', 
    val11 : 'Team11',
    val12 : 'Team12',
    val13 : 'Team13',
    val14 : 'Team14'
};



var listString = '<ul data-role="listview"  data-split-theme="c">';
$.each(myTeamName, function(index, value) {
var a = 1;
var b = 'ss';
    listString +='<li data-icon="false"><a href="#" rel="external" style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;"><label><input id="'+index+'" name="'+index+'" class="item_checkbox" type="checkbox" value="false"/></label><div onclick="fnLoadTeamMember(\''+a+'\')"><h2 style="padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px">'+value+'</h2><p>'+ value +'</p></div></a></li>';
});
listString += '</ul>';
```

Here, If I pass one parameter it's working fine. How did I pass the second parameter? Please do the needful.

Comment: So what is `ss`, is it a variable in the global scope, a variable you're trying to concantenate in the string, or just a string (if so it should be quoted) ?

Comment: Much cleaner would be attaching the events via `.on()` - http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: you need to provide more code, so we can understand what is `myTeamName` and that `ss` variable

Comment: The issue will be with the ss variable, there's no limit in the number of arguments you can pass to a function.

Comment: ss is hard coded string.

Comment: @AdisAksh where is `ss` stored? `console.log(ss)` in your foreach loop and tell us what is outputted

Comment: what is myTeamName?????

Comment: what is the error, you are getting?????????

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle.net for this. it helps alot.
if you are getting ss undefined then you should keep ss globally accessible

Comment: Is fnLoadTeamMember the function that's failing with different numbers of parameters?

Comment: If I pass the above parameter it's working fine. But I want to send 2 parameters. How should I do?

Comment: What breaks? Does your HTML break if you try to add the second parameter? And what does the code look like when you do this? Or does fnLoadTeamMember throw an error when you click on the list item?

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing that, when you try with just 1 parameter, it was a number (like the "2" in (2, ss)). Have you tried passing that "ss" with quotes?

```
 <div onclick="fnLoadTeamMember(2,'ss')">
```

Maybe that would help. I hope it does.

Comment: There's no point passing "ss" into the function if it's the same value every time?

Comment: `ss` is a "hard coded variable", not just the string "ss". Don't jump the gun on an answer just for XP.

Comment: Haha, I didn't. The code didn't explained that when I gave this answer. Anyway, I'll try the code and see if anything comes around.

Comment: If "ss" is a hard coded variable, maybe the problem is the scope. Where is "ss" declared?

Comment: I've asked the OP that exact question in a comment, waiting for a response.

Comment: Yes it's passing the same value.